# Return top level domain WITH language part from a given url in very different formats

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a solution to extract and return from the following URL formats the TLD with language part but without additional paths or parameters. Modern JS/TS with RegEx can be used for this.

```
#1 https://www.mywebsite.com/fr/additional/path/
#2 https://www.mywebsite.com/de/
#3 https://www.mywebsite.de/en/
#4 https://www.mywebsite.de/fr/
#5 https://my.local.dev.env.de/en/one.two
#6 https://www.mywebsite.org/
#7 https://mywebsite.org
#8 https://mywebsite.com/fr/some/path/one.two.three/end/
```

Searching for the last dot at the end of the string does not work (see no. 5 and no. 8.). In addition, not every URL has an additional language part (see no.7). If I search for ".de", for example, it does not work with No. 5 because it contains ".dev".

I don't know if there is a pattern here. TLD has a different length (2-3). Language addition (fr, de, ...) is sometimes included and sometimes not. A URL can have many dots and sometimes there is a slash at the end of the URL and sometimes not.

However, the number of different domains (TLD) is not large (about 20). Perhaps one could define different domains in a JSON object and check against it in a function whether the URL "https://my.local.dev.env.de/fr/" is contained completely in the current opened URL and then search for the last dot and return everything that comes after it?

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `URL` constructor. It can parse any url for you. You can then access its properties to get different parts of the url

```
const lang = new URL(url).pathname.split('/')[1]
```

Comment: Hi, and how to extract top level domain from #5? (https://my.local.dev.env.de/en/one.two)

Comment: `new URL(...).hostname` should extract you the host, or maybe `.origin` will suit your needs better

Comment: console.log(new URL(url).hostname) returns me "my.local.dev.env.de" . Now I need to search for the last dot in the string and extract everything after it. Is there a simple JS function for this or do I need a RegEx? When I have these two parts, I can then combine them and build TLD + LANG. Thank you!

Comment: I think I found a solution with RegEx: `new URL(url).hostname.match(/[^\.]*$/)[0]`. It seems to work. Is this RegEx solution OK? I would then extract TLD and LANG separately and then connect them.

Comment: I would do `.split('.').at(-1)` to extract the last fragment, because there are a lot of developers who don't know regex and hate them because of that. But your solution is good as well